# How do I fix start menu icons that have lighter backgrounds?

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-interface

I've recently installed some apps on my new device and pinned them to the start menu. But a few of them have lighter icon background colours and so they do not fit well with other icons on the start menu. I've tried using Jonno12345's TileIconifier to change the icon background colours but the problem still persists.

Currently using Win10 Home Version 10.0.19042 Build 19042

[image: Light start menu icon backgrounds]

Comment: Aren't they just lighten up to indicate they are new programs? If you open them once, they should go to a gray icon.

Comment: @LPChip I thought that too, but I've already opened them a few times before and the background colour is still the same.

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you using?  You can [edit] your question to include that information

Comment: There are a number of users with windows 10 20H2 experiencing the exact same issue like yours and the problem is probably because windows automatically adds lighter tile if the icon is "too dark". 
The common suggestions are either using earlier versions of applications or adjusted the icons to the background color.

Comment: @Jenny Thank you! Guess it means I have to wait for a windows update that fixes this issue?

Comment: Having the same issue (with the exact same adobe apps!), really wish there was a fix for this